# Merging the knots vector to get the common knots vector

Tags: c, algorithm, merge

Given that I have the following knots vector `U1, U2, U3`

```
U1 = {0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8};
U2 = {0.21, 0.25, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8};
U3 = {0.25, 0.3, 0.7, 0.8};
```

Now I would like to calculate their ***common knots vector*** , i.e., a knots vector that contains all of the elements of  `U1, U2, U3` and has the least length. For example, containing all of the elements of  `U1` means containing 
`{0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8}`, rather than `{0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.8}`.
For this case, the common knots vector of `U1, U2, U3` is:

```
commonKnotsVector = {0.21, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8}
```

---

For the *common knots vector*, my *Mathematica* algorithm as shown below:

[image]

```
commonKnotsVector[knots_] :=
  Module[{step1, step2, step3, step4},
   step1 = SortBy[Join @@ Tally /@ knots, First];
   step2 = GatherBy[step1, First];
   step3 = Last /@ (SortBy[#, Last] & /@ step2);
   step4 = step3 /. {x_, n_} :> ConstantArray[x, n];
   Flatten[step4]
]

commonKnotsVector[{U1, U2, U3}]
(*{0.21, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8}*)
```

#### Question

- Now I would like to know how to deal with this problem in C? I have no idea about C algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned `merge` tag - this is right approach, use algortihm based on three-way `merge` step of [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

You have three sorted vectors. Pseudocode:

```
 While vectors are not empty:
      Find the smallest element among the heads of all vectors
      Extract it into `current` element
      Add `current` to output vector  
      Until next smallest element is equal to `current`: 
           Just remove it from vector head.
```

You can use the simplest priority queue based on binary heap - here heap will contain only three elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following algorithm

```
i   j   k   min_val
1   1   1   0.21    j++
1   2   1   0.25    i++ j++ k++
2   3   2   0.25    i++
3   3   2   0.3     j++ k++
3   4   3   0.5     i++
4   4   3   0.5     i++
5   4   3   0.6     j++
5   5   3   0.7     j++ k++
5   6   4   0.75    i++
6   6   4   0.75    i++
7   6   4   0.8     i++ j++ k++
//===>common vector
U = {0.21, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.75, 0.75, 0.8}
```

#### C function for two vectors

```
#define min_two(a, b) (a) > (b) ? (b) :(a)

//count denotes the length of common vector of U1, U2
int two_vec_common(double *U1, double *U2, int len1, int len2, double *temp) {
    int i, j;
    double min_val;
    int count = 0;
    i = j = 0;
    while (i < len1 || j < len2) {
        min_val = min_two(U1[i], U2[j]);
        temp[count++] = min_val;
        if(U1[i] == min_val) i++;
        if(U2[j] == min_val) j++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

#### C function for three vectors

```
double min_three(double x, double y, double z) {
    if (x <= y && x <= z) return x;
    if (y <= x && y <= z) return y;
    if (z <= x && z <= y) return z;
}
/*count denotes the length of common vector of U1, U2, U3
  len1, len2, len3 denote the length of vector U1, U2, U3, respectively
  the pointer variable temp stores the values of common vector*/
int three_vec_common(double *U1, double *U2, double *U3, int len1, int len2, int len3, double *temp) {
    int i, j, k;
    double min_val;
    int count = 0;
    i = j = k = 0;
    while (i < len1 || j < len2 || k < len3) {
        min_val = min_three(U1[i], U2[j], U3[k]);
        temp[count++] = min_val;
        if(U1[i] == min_val) i++;
        if(U2[j] == min_val) j++;
        if(U3[k] == min_val) k++;
    }
    return count;
}
```